# Using Support Vector Machine with Encog 3 and multiple output

Tags: java, neural-network, time-series, svm, encog

In my previous post I asked about time series forecasting with Encog AI Framework.
Now I have 3 questions related to the possibility of forecasting using Support Vector Machine to forecast multiple outputs.

1)Just to clarify, I would like to predict next 5 days of deviceConsumption using previous 10 days of deviceConsumption and TotalPower.
Is it possible?

2)Does SVMs use the TotalPower and deviceConsumption to build patterns (like an Artificial Neural Network does)?

3)Is it possible to train an ANN or SVM on a training set and save the trained network (for ANN) or SVM trained hyperplane and than, in a second moment, add one value to the tail of the training set and submit this new training set to the previously trained netowork (or SVM) and train again the previously trained network (or SVM) without loosing the results achieved (the heuristics learned)?

Sorry for my English ;-)
Thanks

```
TemporalMLDataSet result = new TemporalMLDataSet(10,5);
TemporalDataDescription desc = new TemporalDataDescription(
TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW,true,true);
result.addDescription(desc);
TemporalDataDescription desc2 = new TemporalDataDescription(
TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW,false,true);
result.addDescription(desc2);

for(int year = TRAIN_START;year<TRAIN_END;year++)
{
    TemporalPoint point = new TemporalPoint(2);
    point.setSequence(year);
    point.setData(0, this.deviceConsumption[year]);
    point.setData(1, this.TotalPower[year]);
    result.getPoints().add(point);

}
result.generate();

SVM svm = new SVM(windowSize,true);
SVMSearchTrain train = new SVMSearchTrain(svm,result);
do {
  train.iteration();
  System.out.println("Epoch #" + train.getIteration() + " Error:" +   train.getError()+ " ");
} while(train.getError()> 0.01);

EncogUtility.evaluate(svm, result);
Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

For questions 1 and 2:

SVM's separate your dataset into two classes. When you train it ends up giving you a hyperplane that separates the two classes. Then when given a new point, you can check this and it will tell you which class it belongs to.

I think what you're looking for is some type of interpolation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Which allows you to get new data points based on previous data.